# remove the blank rows in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I have a [code](https://www.daxpatterns.com/currency-conversion/) as below and I have empty cells in `@Rate` column. How can I get rid of the blank rows using DAX? Many thanks in advance.

```
   Sales USD (Daily) :=
    VAR AggregatedSalesInCurrency =
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE (
                Sales,
                'Date'[Date],                 -- Day granularity
                'Currency'[Currency]
            ),
            "@SalesAmountInCurrency", [Sales (Internal)],
            "@Rate", CALCULATE (
                SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Daily Exchange Rates'[Rate] )
            )
        )
    VAR Result =

SUMX (
        FILTER(AggregatedSalesInCurrency,  [@Rate] <> 0),
        [@SalesAmountInCurrency] / [@Rate]
    ) 

RETURN
{Result} // in daxstudio use {}
```

Comment: Added it in the question, thanks again <3.

Comment: You should use `NOT ISBLANK ( [@Rate ] )` as a best practice.

Comment: Not see your file and not sure about the problem. But I think you can try to replace "[@Rate] <> 0 " into "[@Rate] <> blank() " as empty cells cannot be scratched as 0 but blank.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kq9XDE358I8

Comment: Also use DIVIDE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/divide-function-dax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SUMX (         
   FILTER(AggregatedSalesInCurrency,  [@Rate] <> 0),  
  [@SalesAmountInCurrency] / [@Rate]     
)
```

Comment: thanks, it doesnt work. I guess the order it matters. number/0 gives error.

Comment: I've update to filter out zeroes. Does this one work?

Comment: `SUMX (
        FILTER(AggregatedSalesInCurrency,  [@Rate] <> 0),
        [@SalesAmountInCurrency] / [@Rate]
    )`  and {Result} seems working, thanks a lot.